# Free Text in Dropdown List - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

I am currently implementing a form in CodeIgniter that needs to have a drop down select that takes data from a database, this is easy enough, however I would like to have an open text selection available too, preferably not creating a new form input box but having a free text where the select sits.

Would anyone know a way to achieve this, I have been thinking there must be a way to use Ajax or something for this but I cannot for the life of me work it out.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to fake it with a ul.  When someone types in text a search of options is triggered? Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I was intending to have a drop down <select> but if the user did not like those available options they could use their free text option so basically it is an "other" option for the dropdown but with free text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events wont work on options so no!

You could try something like this [semi solution](http://jsfiddle.net/psuUb/5/)

Would need to be tweaked a little. be careful to add the values manually yourself.  {note:} after your done with the other element, remove it! else it will show for all the options when you re-select them.

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery's autocomplete plugin, it will fill your requirement [click here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: I'm not trying to autocomplete a free text entry though, basically I am giving users examples of questions they can use through the use of a select drop down and was aiming to have a free text option open for people who don't want to use the sample questions

Comment: @Aaron you are not describing your problem in the proper way. what the mean by free text on select box, if you are not trying to autocomplete ?

Comment: I want a drop down select input on a form that if the user selects other they get a free text entry where the drop down should be.